# Randomly value combine in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet with lot of data in cell a and in cell b in cell c just have 5 row's . I want to combine these 5 values with cell B's data Randomly . For ex:

```
Cell A |  Cell B  |  Cell C  | Cell D 
======================================
data 1 |  this is | my photo  |this is our photo
data 2 | this is  |your photo |this is my photo     
data 3 | this is  | our photo |this is your photo
data 4 | this is  |           | this is my photo
data 5 | this is  |           | this is our photo
```

hope you understand my question . Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In **D1** enter:

```
=B1 & INDEX($C$1:$C$3,RANDBETWEEN(1,3))
```

and copy down.  For example:

[image]